# Highchart return image before bar (yAxis)

Tags: javascript, image, highcharts

I'm working with HighCharts (bar charts). I need to put image (wrapped in div) before each bar, like on a picture below.

Any idea how to do that ? I've tryed to return img with something like in jsfiddle example below , but unsuccessfull. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3dLkms/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if(this.value == "Jun")
                        return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />'+this.value;
                    else if(this.value == "Dec")
                         return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />'+this.value;
                    else
                        return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Example what I need: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWHge.png)

Comment: Can you clarify the code you are using a bit? What is wrong with the highcharts example you provided?

Comment: This code works for images on xAxis. I need to return images to yAxis.

I've tryed to add similar code in yAxis labels properties, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r4w71vew/ or http://jsfiddle.net/wzx1p9wx/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!

BIG THANKS!